# Drop-down menu selection stored in a variable such as $title

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a short form with drop-down menu. I have populated it with title options such as Mr, Mrs etc. What I'm trying to achieve is store the value of the selected option in variable $title.

This is my code:

```
<select name="title" id="title" form="titleForm">
     <option value="mr">Mr</option>
     <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
     <option value="miss">Miss</option>
     <option value="ms">Ms</option>
</select>
```

PHP code to store the value in a variable.

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

It's worked for textboxes but doesn't for the drop-down menu.
Everything works apart from the drop-down menu one:

```
    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $varFirstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $varLastName = $_POST['lastName'];

    $title = $_POST['title'];

    echo "$title $varFirstName $varLastName";
}
```

@EDIT
Somehow I've managed to figure it out. I've created another echo and put my $title there. Not sure why it caused issues but worked at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

`$varTitle = $_POST['title'];` It worked for `dropdown` to. By using this you can get the `value` of selected `option` from the `dropdown`. In case you want the `selected text` then you have to put it in some hidden field on the selection change and get the value of that hidden field on form submit.

Comment: I'm trying to echo the value at the end. So far I have the first name and last name but can't get the echo to print Mr. for example.

Comment: Are you using form `post` method or jquery `ajax()`?

Comment: Simplest post method. I have no knowledge about jquery.

Comment: With form post `$_POST['title'];` will definitely work

Comment: The code in this answer looks exactly the same as the PHP code is the question. Am I overlooking something? @Lazio is you question now answered? If yes, what made te difference? :confused:

Comment: @PaulvanLeeuwen: Yes the code is the same, but with a proper explanation.

Comment: This is an error I get "Notice: Undefined index: title in E:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\QueueApp\process.php on line 9". PhpStorm always points the variables I can use in a current scenario but this time title didn't even appear on the list if you know what I mean. Weird. The "title" appears in the code.